# Image uploader architecture in a Node.js environment

Tags: node.js

As I understand, Node has just one main thread that never stops, as it just dispatches actions to a pool with a callback function to run when the action is done. The actions enter to a queue and once they're done, your callback function is called with the action results.

So, say I want to build an app to upload pics and I'm going to use Node in the backend. The pics need to be processed (resizing, recoding,...) and it's not a good idea to do this directly in Node. Say we have a really optimized C++ app that does this.

What could I do? I don't know if I could directly call my c++ program from Node with a callback function. In theory this would make sense, as Node already has a pool, so images would just process at a constant rate without bothering the server. Does this make any sense? If it does, how would you do it? Say you have the path to the c++ program, could you just directly use it on Node, or you would need an interface listening on some port for dealing with this?

Is it even a good idea to create a system for uploading pics using Node?

Comment: see the child_process module: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Have you looked at SWIG? http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html